# Definite integral of an exponential quotient

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was wondering if someone could help me find the definite integral of this:

$$ \int\limits_{R1}^{R2} \frac{t\, dt}{(t^2 + K^2)^{3/2}} $$

Where $\,K,\, R1,\, R2\,$ are constants, $\,R2>R1\,$ , and $\,t\,$ is the variable to be used in the integration.
It's been a while since I've done calculus. Can anyone help me? Thank you!!

Comment: inb4 "what is this, a formula for ants??"

Comment: Why $x'$, and not $x,y,t,u...$?

Comment: sorry, mathTeX was pushing together x and dx so it looked like xd x - i wanted to delimit them somehow. ' was a bad choice now in hindsight, my bad sorry.

Comment: No worries, I was just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming K is constant...
$$
\frac{xdx}{(x^{2}+k^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
$$
Let t = $x^2 + k^2$,
Then $dt = 2xdx$ or $xdx = \frac{dt}{2}$
Replace $xdx$ and $x^2+k^2$ in the equation with $dt/2$ and $t$ respectively.

What you get is 
$$
\frac{t^{\frac{-3}{2}}dt}{2}
$$

which when integrated gives $\frac{1}{-(x^2+k^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$

Put int the limits to get
$$
\frac{1}{(R1^2+k^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}} - \frac{1}{(R2^2+k^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}
$$

I hope you can do the rest of the simplification..

Comment: Edited..Sorry and Thanks

Comment: You're a life saver. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$$\int\frac{x\,dx}{(x^2+K)^n}=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2x\,dx}{(x^2+K)^n}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x^2+K)^{1-n}}{1-n}+C(=\text{constant})\;\;,\;\;n\neq 1$$